# what is wrong with this mysql syntax? giving error on first primary key

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

it is giving me an syntax error but i cannot pinpoint what's wrong.

```
use test;
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_EXPENSE
  (
    "EMP_EXP_ID" INT    NOT NULL,
    "EMP_ID" INT(5,0),
    "YEAR" INT(4,0),
    "MONTH"         INT(2,0),
    "EXPENSE_CLAIM" INT(7,2),
    "APPROVED_AMT"  INT(7,2),
    "PAID_DATE" DATE,
    CONSTRAINT "EMP_EXP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_EXP_ID"), 
    CONSTRAINT "FK_EMPLOYEE" FOREIGN KEY ("EMP_ID") REFERENCES "EMPLOYEE" ("EMP_ID") ENABLE
  );
```

mysql workbench shows red squibles under first EMP_EXP_ID.

here's employee table.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
    EMP_ID            INT(5)    NOT NULL,
    FNAME             VARCHAR(20),
    LNAME             VARCHAR(20),
    DEPT_ID           INT(5)    NOT NULL,
    MANAGER_EMP_ID    INT(5),
    SALARY            INT(5),
    HIRE_DATE         DATE,
    JOB_ID            INT(3),
    ACTIVE            CHAR(1)  DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (EMP_ID)
);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: sql syntax error near... and it starts with EMP_EXP_ID....

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the quotes around the column identifiers. They are incorrect. Either use ticks or nothing at all.

```
use test;
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_EXPENSE
  (
    EMP_EXP_ID INT    NOT NULL,
    EMP_ID INT(5,0),
    YEAR INT(4,0),
    MONTH         INT(2,0),
    EXPENSE_CLAIM INT(7,2),
    APPROVED_AMT  INT(7,2),
    PAID_DATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT EMP_EXP_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMP_EXP_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID) ENABLE
  );
```

Comment: OP didn't do the tick-thang, but I'll give a helping hand ;-)